# Is there a way to have a field that only the superuser can add/edit?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, wagtail

Is there a way to have a field that only the superuser can add/edit?

```
class ProductPage(Page):
    price = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    description = RichTextField(blank=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Above is part of my model but i only want the superuser to access the featured field.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean that only superusers logged in the Django admin site should be able to edit the `featured` field. If you want to restrict access in your own forms and views, you just need to check the user's status and customize the form/view accordingly. Here's what you can do in *admin.py*, in your `ModelAdmin`:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request):
    fields = super().get_readonly_fields(request)
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        fields.append('featured')
    return fields
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried out the solution given by @dirkgroten but had to make a few changes to make it work.

According to the [Django Documentation](https://django.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.x/_modules/django/contrib/admin/options.html) for >2.1 versions of Django, the `get_readonly_fields` take 3 parameters.

Also, fields need to set a list to append, as it creates a tuple on default.

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    fields = list(super().get_readonly_fields(request))
    if not request.user.is_superuser:
        fields.append('featured')
    return fields
```